# Oracle APEX - Interactive Grid only displays first 40 records

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid that shows total of 520 records total but only displays first 40. The rest comes up as blank. How can I diagnose the issue?

I tried sorting on different columns and refreshing but still, only 40 records are shown

Comment: For anyone else that might run into this problem, this is a recurring bug for the 23.1.3 version of Oracle Apex. The problem is however fixed in the 23.2.0, in case you happen to be using these versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue; happens when the **Pagination type** property (found in IG's Attributes) is set to **Scroll**. Set it to "Page", see if it helps.